# Can I interchange $\max$ and $\sup$?

Tags: normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Can I interchange $\max$ and $\sup$? To be honest I do not know if this is true.

I am working with the following problem. I would like to prove that

$$\max \left\{\,\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,\; t\sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\,\right\} \,=\, \sup_{t>0}\max\{|f(t)|,t|g(t)|\}.$$

*My attempt:*

For all $t>0$, we have that $|f(t)|\leq \sup_{t>0}|f(t)|$ and $t|g(t)|\leq t \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|$.

Then $|f(t)|\leq \max\{\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,  t \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\}$, and similarly,

$$t|g(t)|\leq \max\{\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,  t \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\}. $$

Therefore,
$$\max\{|f(t)|,t|g(t)|\}\leq \max\{\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,  t \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\}$$ implies that
$$\sup_{t>0}\max\{|f(t)|,t|g(t)|\}\leq \max\{\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,  t \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\}.$$
Am i right to here?

For the other inequality i can not yet. Some ideas are to use properties from $\sup$ as for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $t_*>0$: $\sup|f(t)|\leq |f(t_*)|+\epsilon$. A similar argument for $g$ perhaps help me.

$$\sup|g(t)|\leq |g(t_*)|+\epsilon, \\ t\sup|g(t)|\leq t|g(t_*)|+\epsilon t.$$

Perhaps somebody can help me please or give me hints or tell me that is no true my statement. Thank you.

Comment: Maximum is also a supremum  and you can always interchange two suprema.

Comment: Thank you @geetha290krm i am processing your answer, $\sup =\max$ ?

Comment: @weymarandres maximum is the supremum of a finite set. It's sort of a specialized supremum for that case.

Comment: thank you @CyclotomicField is true!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding your question. But if not, then the equality doesn't hold.

E.g., if $f(t)=1$, and $g(t)=0$ if $t\neq1$ and $g(1)=2$, then $\max(f(t),tg(t))=1$ whenever $t\neq1$ and is $2$ otherwise.

So, $\sup_{t>0}\max(f(t),tg(t))=2$. On the other hand, $t\sup_{t>0}g(t)=2t$, which is unbounded.

Comment: Even me I do not know if my question is well , but your example help me so much to building other similar thing, thank you @Vit

Comment: There is way to do not take account the term $t$, i mean just to take $\sup$ over the function $g$ but not at $tg(t)$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you asking whether $\max \left\{\,\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,\; \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\,\right\} \,=\, \sup_{t>0}\max\{|f(t)|,|g(t)|\}$?If yes, then yes. Suppose $\sup_{t>0}|g(t)| \leq \sup_{t>0}|f(t)|$, put $m(t)=max(|f(t)|,|g(t)|)$. $\max \left\{\,\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,\; \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\,\right\}=\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|$. Since $|f(t)| \leq   m(t)$, $\sup_{t>0}|f(t)| \leq \sup_{t>0}m(t)$. On the other hand, $m(t) \leq  \max \left\{\,\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,\; \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\,\right\}=\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|$, hence $\sup_{t>0}m(t)=\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|$.

Comment: To clarify my last sentence, $m(t) \leq  \max \left\{\,\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|,\; \sup_{t>0}|g(t)|\,\right\}=\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|$ implies $\sup_{t>0}m(t)\leq\sup_{t>0}|f(t)|$ and together with $\sup_{t>0}|f(t)| \leq \sup_{t>0}m(t)$ we get $\sup_{t>0}|f(t)| =\sup_{t>0}m(t)$

Comment: thank you for your time. In middle of my question yes i asked your result, is very helpful for me your answer. Thank you so much!!!